# Angular CSS Not Being Applied To 'mat-grid-list'

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an `Angular 6` application and I have a page where I have a `mat-card` which contains a `mat-grid-list` with 3 columns.

Within the `mat-grid-list` I have 3 empty `span` to display an empty coloured square with a label at the end.

I have created my `CSS` and referenced it in my `HTML` file but it only seems to work for my first `span` and also my first `CSS`

**CSS**

```
.complaintSquare {
    background-color: #ffb2b2;
};

.enquirySquare {
    background-color: red;
};

.otherSquare {
    background-color: green;
};
```

**HTML**

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-title class="thirdCard">Notes</mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-grid-list cols="3">
      <span>
        <span class="complaintSquare"> &nbsp;  &nbsp; </span>
          &nbsp;Complaint
      </span>
      <span>
        <span class="enquirySquare"> &nbsp;  &nbsp; </span>
        &nbsp;Enquiry
      </span>
      <span>            
        <span class="otherSquare"> &nbsp;  &nbsp; </span>
        &nbsp;Other
      </span>
    </mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: plz add your component.ts file. CSS file may not be added in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that all you your css classes have a semicolon (;) at the end -

You css should look like this -

```css
.complaintSquare {
    background-color: #ffb2b2;
}

.enquirySquare {
    background-color: red;
}

.otherSquare {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-title class="thirdCard">Notes</mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-grid-list cols="3">
      <span>
        <span class="complaintSquare"> &nbsp;  &nbsp; </span>
          &nbsp;Complaint
      </span>
      <span>
        <span class="enquirySquare"> &nbsp;  &nbsp; </span>
        &nbsp;Enquiry
      </span>
      <span>            
        <span class="otherSquare"> &nbsp;  &nbsp; </span>
        &nbsp;Other
      </span>
    </mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: completely code blinded. I tried everything copy and pasting the `CSS` name etc and nothing. Hate when this happens but thanks

Comment: This is a nightmare which happens once in a while with every developer. Happy to help you clear it off your backlog as soon as I could. Cheers!